# Unable to edit cells in multiple rows at once in AG_grid 30

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to the keep all the edited rows in the `ag-grid` in editing mode, with latest version of `ag-grid` v30.1 And `Angular` v14.

I have few rows in `ag-grid` with edit button on each row at the end. Once i click the edit icon, i show the cells in that particular row into editing mode. When i click edit on next row, i want to keep the previous edited row and the latest edited row in editing mode.

I Achieved this by using "startEdtingcell" in `gridApi`.
Example: i am pushing ID's of edited rows into one array and looping through it to keep all the rows in editing mode.

Code:

```
this.editedRows= [1, 2,3]

for( const item of this.editedRows){
this.gridApi.startEditingCell({
rowIndex: item,
colKey: 'sno' // column name
})
};
```

This was working fine when my `Angular` version was 12  and `ag-grid` version was 26.1

Recently , I upgraded my `Angular` version to 14 and `ag-grid` to 30.1,

Since the version update, i am not able to keep multiple rows in editing mode, only the latest row is showing as editing mode.